# Class inclusion error in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, build-error

I am currently working in visual studio developing a text based game. I had a namespace conflict with a class.
I had a class name which was `Clothing` and namespace which also named Clothing. To get around this issue I renamed the namespace **clothes** instead of clothing and then all the drama started. My csproj file did not update the namespace references in the folders whenever i try to build i get the following error.

```
[Failure] Could not find file '...\src\Items\Equipment\Apparel\Clothing\Shirts\Shirt.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file '...\src\Items\Equipment\Apparel\Clothing\ClothingEnum.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file '...\src\Items\Equipment\Apparel\Clothing\Cloaks\Cloak.cs'.
[Failure] Could not find file '...\src\Items\Equipment\Apparel\Clothing\Boots\JackBoot.cs'.
...
```

If i look in these directories the files exist but are empty. The actual files are in ...\src\Items\Equipment\Apparel\ **Clothes**\Boots... and they are included in the csproj file. But these files are also there.

In essence what I'm asking is how do I remove these unused references/dependencies/whatever they are from the csproj file.

Manually deleting the xml references in csproj file just causes my project to fail loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get why you renamed your folders after you renamed the namespaces - that is unnecessary, in my opinion.

You can remove the cs files from the solution explorer with "Exclude from project"and then add the new ones with "Add -> Existing item"

Comment: this worked thank you. I thought that namespaces and folder names were linked.

Comment: VS makes namespaces (when it creates .cs files) follow folder structure for usability and readability, but it's not mandatory to keep it that way. It's a bit more important in some big projects that many people work on.